# Background pixeled image android

Tags: android, image, background, pixel

I'm trying to set a background image in the main layout of an app that i'm developing. I've tryed setting the image in the hdpi, mdpi, etc folders, but the image always get pixeled in bad resolution.

How can i set a good background image with good resolution?

Comment: You should provide more info, like image resolution. format and resolution of screen you've tryed it

Comment: The image is .jpg format (1280*1024), and I'm developing in a virtual device 3,7"